# Don't know how to treat that as a predicate

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to run a custom query in my repository, but I'm getting a InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException. "Don't know how to treat that as a predicate String("n.id = '1234'")".

```
public void myMethod() {
    myRepository.queryUsingCustomFilters("n.id = '1234'");
}

public interface MyRepository() extends Neo4jRepository<MyObject, String> {
    @Query("MATCH (n) WHERE {filter} RETURN n")
    List<MyObject> queryUsingCustomFilters(@Param("filter") String filter);
}
```

I have a simple example for now, but the string I'm passing in the future could be a little bit more complicated, such as "n.id = '1234' AND (n.name = 'one name' OR n.name = 'another name')"

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can pass entire clauses/predicates/queries as a `@Param`.
If you want to build queries at run time, you might want to look at composing it using the lower level [Neo4j OGM](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/3.2/) filters (see https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:filters)

So in the case you describe above, you could simply add `Filter`s as required and chain them together to build your `WHERE` clause

Comment: How do I use these Filters in my repository?

Comment: The filters are an OGM concept, so you would have to write code for this in your service methods

Comment: Oh I see, I think I got it, so I am using this example https://www.baeldung.com/java-neo4j alongside the neo4j link you sent me to try to make this work, however the session object used in that example is not the same used in the neo4j website, I'm trying to figure out how the session in the neo site is initialized

Btw thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. The Session I refer to is the Neo4j OGM session (not a Bolt session). Here are some tests which should demonstrate how they're used: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/neo4j-ogm-tests/neo4j-ogm-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/session/request/strategy/impl/NodeQueryStatementsTest.java and https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/master/neo4j-ogm-tests/neo4j-ogm-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/persistence/examples/cineasts/annotated/CineastsIntegrationTest.java

Comment: It seems like that approach is very complicated, how do you determine how to initialize the session factory?

Comment: Yes, it really is a low level API. You can get a session like this https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/#tutorial-session
If you don't want to drop to this level, then perhaps just construct the entire query string in code based on the rules, and execute a simple query, passing in the parameters